# How can I protect a matrix in R from being altered by Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I am making a package containing two Rcpp functions. The first function is used for creating a matrix that will be used several times by the second function. The matrix is stored in R's global environment between calls to the two functions.

```
M <- myFirstRcpp(X)
P <- mySecondRcpp(M)
```

Depending on input parameters the second function will make changes to the input matrix (created by the first function) before calculating a vector from it (`aFunction` is the C++ inside `mySecondRcpp()`):

```
IntegerVector aFunction( SEXP Qin, SEXP param ) {
    NumericMatrix Q(Qin);
    // Some changes made to Q
    ...
    // return a vector generated from Q
}
```

My problem is that the changes done to the `Q` matrix inside the second Rcpp function also affect the copy of the matrix (`M`) residing in R's global environment.

How can I prevent Rcpp from altering the global environment of R without too much overhead?

Notes: The `M` matrix is ~2000x65000 in size. The problem occurs with R 3.0.2 and Rcpp 0.10.6 on Windows and Linux in 32 and 64 bit R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a known and documented feature.  We are being called from R via the interface

```
  SEXP somefunction(SEXP a, SEXP b, ...)
```

so a *pointer* is being passed and changes to `Q` affect the outer object. *That is a good thing* as it makes the calls very fast -- no copies.

If you want distinct instances, use the `clone()` method as in

```
  NumericMatrix Q = clone(Qin);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dirk! I was searching for this, but overlooked it in the documentation. This is of course very useful when not being used the wrong way (as I was doing).

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do from within R (e.g., when you cannot easily edit the `Rcpp` code) is to call a `[` method on the R object reference. This forces R to pass a copy. For example,

```
M <- myFirstRcpp(X)
P <- mySecondRcpp(M[])`
```

Now, `M` will not get altered by side-effects from `mySecondRcpp()`.