# Rcpp Copy a vector to a vector

Tags: c++, vector, copy, rcpp

I am new to Rcpp and C++ coding in general, so forgive me for asking basic questions. The cpp part of the code is

```
// test.cpp

#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void testRun() {
   IntegerVector Grp1 = IntegerVector::create(1,2,3,4);
   IntegerVector Grp2 = IntegerVector::create(3,4,5,6);

   Rf_PrintValue(Grp1);
   Grp1 = Grp2;
   Rf_PrintValue(Grp1);
   Grp2[3] = Grp2[3]+1;
   Rf_PrintValue(Grp1);
}
```

and when I run testrun(), I get the output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('test.cpp')
> testRun()
[1] 1 2 3 4
[1] 3 4 5 6
[1] 3 4 5 7
```

When I assign `Gr2` to `Gr1` in `Gr1 = Gr2`, changing elements in `Gr2` after the assignment changes the values in `Gr1` as well. Is there a function for IntegerVectors that could do something like `Gr1 = copy of Gr2` or should I be using a loop to do that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you mean  `Rcpp::clone()` as in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21282929/143305 as well as others?

Answer (score 9):

As hinted in the comment, you could use

```
Grp1 = clone(Grp2) ;
```

but this will create a new R object that then get assigned to `Grp1`, so you pay for some memory allocation and you discard some memory that could have been used, i.e. more work for the garbage collector down the line.

You could also just reuse the existing memory from `Grp1` with [std::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/)

```
std::copy( Grp2.begin(), Grp2.end(), Grp1.begin() ) ;
```

Another way that is perhaps over the top is to use `sapply`. Something like this:

```
auto identity = [](double x){ return x; } ;
Grp1 = sapply( Grp2, identity );
```

But given `Rcpp` does not [sapply over lambdas](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/213), you'd probably have to define `identity` outside your function for this approach to be useable.

```
inline double identity(double x){ 
    return x ;
}
```

FWIW, in `Rcpp14` or `Rcpp11`, you could simply do:

```
Grp1 = import(Grp2) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

What is currently happening is a very common error with pointers. Grp1 and Grp2 are pointers, so setting one equal to the other means that they point to the same array (and any changes to one array will affect the other). One solution would be to use a iterator to copy all values over one at a time. This would be done by emptying one IntegerVector by popping all values and then pushing all elements from the other IntegerVector into the emptied IntegerVector.

Comment: popping and pushing would lead to dramatic performance for Rcpp types, as this means lots of data allocation, etc ...