# what does sizeof return for RCpp vectors

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to understand what the c++ `sizeof` does when operating on an RCpp vector. As an example:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('int size_of(NumericVector a) {return(sizeof a);}')
size_of(1.0)
# [1] 16
```

this returns the value 16 for any numeric or integer vector passed to it.

As also does

```
cppFunction('int size_of(IntegerVector a) {return(sizeof a);}')
size_of(1)
# [1] 16
```

I thought that numerics in R were 8 bytes and integers 4 bytes. So what is going on here?  The motivation is to use `memcpy` on RCpp vectors, for which the size needs to be known.

Comment: Just so I'm the first to say it: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit - corrected

Comment: *I'm trying to understand what the c++ sizeof does* -- It does nothing different than what it's supposed to do -- return the `sizeof()` the type, in bytes.

Comment: @dww Out of curiousity, what platform are you on?  Why is your pointer size 16 bytes when mine on Linux is 8?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel mine is 16 too on linux 64 bits

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'm on Linux, 64 bit (kernel 4.13.0-37).

Comment: Thinko on my part then.  SEXP is 8 bytes, our types _contain_ a SEXP but are bigger.  So just ignore what I said above :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Everything* we pass from R to C(++) and return is a `SEXP` type -- a *pointer* to an S Expression.

So if we generalize your function and actually let a `SEXP` in, we can see some interesting things:

```
R> Rcpp::cppFunction('int size_of(SEXP a) {return(sizeof a);}')
R> size_of(1L)    ## single integer -- still a pointer
[1] 8 
R> size_of(1.0)   ## single double -- still a pointer
[1] 8
R> size_of(seq(1:100))   ## a sequence ...
[1] 8
R> size_of(help)         ## a function
[1] 8
R> size_of(globalenv)    ## an environment
[1] 8
R>
```

in short you got caught between a compile-time C++ type analysis operator (`sizeof`) and the run-time feature that everything is morphed into the `SEXP` type.  For actual vectors, you probably want the `size()` or `length()` member functions and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to get into how `NumericVector` and `IntegerVector` are implemented to discover why they statically take up a certain number of bytes.

Based on your observation of the size of a "numeric" or "integer" in this context, it is likely that the value 16 accounts for any/all of the following:

- Pointer to [dynamically-allocated?] data
- Current logical size of container (number of elements)
- Any other metadata

Ideally, don't use `memcpy` to transfer the state of one object to another, unless you are **absolutely certain** that it is a trivial object with only members of built-in type. If I have correctly guessed the layout of a `NumericVector`, using `memcpy` on it will violate its ownership semantics and thus be incorrect. There are [other ways to copy R vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28671945/560648).

Comment: Answer is close, but it is a little different.  There is a 'small size' optimization that keep vectors up to a certain size fixed when you look at them from R via `object.size()` -- it will always be 88 bytes for vectors of up to 12 elements, then 104 bytes up to 16 and so on.

Comment: That was for integer elements, for double it is half the cutoff.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Not bad for someone who's literally never touched R in their life, though, right? :)

Comment: Indeed! I have enjoyed _many_ of your other posts though hence just trying to toss a little bone of appreciation :)   (And R internals are weird.  Which makes them fun for different definitions of the latter.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Getting a Zend vibe off the tiny window into the world I've seen in your answer. Not sure whether that's good or bad.